# Angular 4 Component of sub module is not working when using in root/main module

Tags: angular

I have a angular module (@ngModule) named SubModule which contains a component named SubComponent with css selector 'app-subcomp'.

I have imported this sub module into my AppModule (application shell). So my AppModule (@ngModule) contains AppComponent with 'app-root' css selector and one sub module (SubModule).

When i write '< app-subcomp >' into my app.component.html, it is not rendering sub.component.html.

but when i directly declare my SubComponent into AppModule, its working  fine.

Not sure why it is not rendering in first case?

Please  suggest.

Thank You

**sub.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { SubComponent } from './sub.component'; 

@NgModule({ 
     imports: [ CommonModule ], 
     declarations: [SubComponent], 
}) 
export class SubModule { }
```

Comment: We can play a million posts or you can share your code

Comment: did you export the SubComponent in sub module? Share the sub module.ts code

Comment: Hi Deepak,Below is the submodule code      -                                   
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SubComponent } from './sub.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [SubComponent],
  
})
export class SubModule { }

Comment: @Atul not recommended posting question code in comment section. Just edit question, copy-paste code to your post, highlight pasted code and hit ctrl+k to convert to code format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to export `SubComponent`:

```
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [ CommonModule ], 
    declarations: [SubComponent], 
    exports: [SubComponent], 
}) 
export class SubModule { }
```